# With QGIS, how can I create a layer from a .csv file?

Tags: qgis, csv

I have a .csv file with ~16k points with lat and long to plot onto a map. I'm completely new to both QGIS and GIS in general and have got to a point where I have downloaded the OpenLayers and Georeferencer plugins and have a raster satellite image, but my data points are all collected off the coast of Africa at a much smaller scale than the map itself.

However, when I try to use the Georeferencer plugin it only lets me add a raster image from my local files (unless there is an option I haven't seen), yet the image I am using is from a plugin; I'm not sure if there is any way of finding it from my home directory to load it into the Georeferencer.

How do I georeference a map loaded with OpenLayers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to georeference OpenLayers layers.

In fact, your point data is not projected correctly. To fix that: Go to the CSV layer's properties and change the CRS to WGS84 EPSG:4326 (because that tells QGIS that the points are in lat/lon).